# Shannon capacity definition

Tags: graph-theory

I have seen the Shannon capacity defined in two ways:

$\Theta(G) = \sup_k \sqrt[k]{\alpha(G^k)}$

$\Theta(G) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{\alpha(G^k)}$

My question is, basically, how do we know the limit (in the bottom one) exists, and how do we know the two definitions are equal?

$G^k$, by the way, stands for the strong product of $k$ copies of $G$.

I do know that $\alpha(G \boxtimes H) \geq \alpha(G) \cdot \alpha(H)$.  To see this, let $I_G$, $I_H$ be independent sets in $G$ and $H$.  Then, $I_G \times I_H$ is independent in $G \boxtimes H$.  At first, I mistakenly decided this meant the sequence $\sqrt[k]{\alpha(G^k)}$ must be nondecreasing.  From this, I made sense that the supremum and limit are the same.  Since an upper bound is $\chi(\bar{G})$, the limit definition exists.  But, this was a bad assumption.  I have discovered, using Sage, that

$\alpha(C_5) = 2$

$\sqrt{\alpha(C_5^2)} = \sqrt{5}$

$\sqrt[3]{\alpha(C_5^3)} = \sqrt[3]{10}$

And, $\sqrt{5} > \sqrt[3]{10}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that the graph is not complete. Let $\alpha_n := \alpha(G^n)$; we need the following facts (noted by the OP in the question):

1. $\alpha_n$ is montononically increasing.
2. $\alpha_n \geqslant 2$.
3. $\alpha_{n+m} \geqslant \alpha_n \alpha_m$.
4. $\alpha_{nm} \geqslant \alpha_n^m$. (This is a corollary of item (3).)
5. $\alpha_n \geqslant \alpha_1^n \geqslant 2^n$.

Let $L$ be the supremum of $\alpha_n^{1/n}$ for all $n$. From (5.), it is clear that $L \geqslant 2$. We want to prove that $\alpha_n^{1/n}$ approaches $L$ as $n \to \infty$.

Fix any $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. Then there exists $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $\alpha_k \geqslant (L - \varepsilon)^k$. Now, for any $n$, define $q := \lfloor n/k \rfloor$. Then we have the following chain of inequalities:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha_n 
&\geqslant& 
\alpha_{kq} 
\\ &\geqslant& 
\alpha_k^q 
\\ &\geqslant& 
(L - \varepsilon)^{kq} 
\\ &\stackrel{(*)}{\geqslant}&
(L - \varepsilon)^{n - k} 
\\ &\geqslant&
\frac{(L - \varepsilon)^n}{L^{k}} 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
As an exercise, justify the above steps carefully. [[The following facts are helpful to show $(\ast)$: (i) $kq \geqslant n - k + 1 \geqslant n - k$; and (ii) $L - \varepsilon \geqslant 2 - 1 = 1$.]]

From the chain of inequalities, we can conclude that
$$
\alpha_n^{1/n} \geqslant  \frac{L - \varepsilon}{L^{k/n}}.
$$
Now, taking $n$ sufficiently large, we can make the denominator at most, say, $1 + \varepsilon$. That is, there exists some $N$ such that for all $n \geqslant N$, we have $\alpha_n^{1/n} \geqslant \frac{L - \varepsilon}{1 + \varepsilon}$. Since $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\alpha_n^{1/n} \to L$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I thank you for the reply.  But, I am seeing a few errors.  I think you misunderstood some of the things I was saying.  $\alpha_{n+m}$ is not necessarily $\alpha_n \alpha_m$.  For example, take $n=m=1$ and look at the $C_5$ example above.  $\alpha_n$ can be 1 in general.  In the specific $C_5$ example, yes, $\geq 2$ but I'm asking in general for any graph.

Comment: @Graphth Apologies. It is indeed not the case that $\alpha_{n+m} = \alpha_n \alpha_m$. What is true (and what I do need in my answer) is that $\alpha_{n+m} \geqslant \alpha_n \alpha_m$. I will edit my answer accordingly. EDIT: Is the answer with the modification ok?

Comment: Hopefully you noticed I just edited my comment as one thing I said was incorrect.  I have corrected my comment and I think it should be fine now.

Comment: Yes, I agree $\alpha_{n+m} \geq \alpha_n \alpha_m$.  I actually must go right now but I will check this answer in the morning.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Graphth One clarification w.r.t. notation. $\alpha_n$ is $\alpha(G^n)$ and not $\alpha(G^n)^{1/n}$. While it is true that $\alpha(G^n)^{1/n}$ is not necessarily  increasing, the sequence $\alpha(G^n) = \alpha_n$ is monotonically increasing as assumed by the answer.

Comment: I have looked over your proof and I still think maybe there is a slight error, but one that is easily fixed.  Right at the end, as $n \to \infty$, $L^{k/n} \to 1$.  So, we can not say that if $n$ is sufficiently large, then $L^{k/n} \geq 1 + \epsilon$... because as $n$ gets bigger and bigger, $L^{k/n}$ actually becomes less than $1 + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$.  Or I am just confused?

Comment: But, I think there is an easy fix.  Just take the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$ of both sides.  The right hand side goes to $L - \epsilon$.  Thus, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\alpha_n)^{1/n} \geq L - \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\alpha_n)^{1/n} \geq L$.  Adding in the fact that the limit must be bounded above by $L$ based on the supremum, we see that the limit must be $L$.

Comment: @Graphth You are correct. That should read "at most 1+epsilon". The basic idea is that the denominator goes to $1$ as $n \to \infty$. Thanks for the catch! (Or alternatively, as you point out, you can take the limit as $n \to \infty$ as well.)

Comment: And, lastly, I want to say thank you for all your help.  And, you are exactly correct that I was thinking $\alpha_n = \alpha(G^n)^{1/n}$ at first.